# rolling over fails for log4j after reloading Web App

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j

I'm facing a problem with log4j 1.2. I'm using a RollingFileAppender and it works perfectly until I reload the web app. then with max size allowed is exceeded, the log files start to get deleted. and the more logs written, more log files will be deleted until no backup files remained. and what bothers me more, that the rolling strategy stops and no new backup files are created (just appending to the same original file). It's like it just becomes a File appender after reloading instead of Rolling File Appender with a fixed-max-size.

Here is how the log4j.properties look:

```
#Properties file used to configure a Log4J logger

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

#A custom logger
log4j.logger.app.log=DEBUG, console, app
log4j.additivity.app=false

#Definition of appenders used by loggers above
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS}] %-5p - %m%n

####################################################################
# logger for application
####################################################################

#Default Config file for CompositeRollingAppender
log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.CompositeRollingAppender
log4j.appender.app.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSS}] %-5p %m%n

#How to perform rolling -- Composite is the default
log4j.appender.app.RollingStyle=3

#Use same file name for all inprocess logging?
log4j.appender.app.staticLogFileName=true
log4j.appender.app.File=C:/Path/app.log

#Size Rolling params
log4j.appender.app.CountDirection=-1
#10M
log4j.appender.app.MaxFileSize=10485760
log4j.appender.app.MaxSizeRollBackups=10

#Date Rolling params
log4j.appender.app.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH

#layout options
log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: how is your log4j prop file looks like..

Comment: Sorry .. I've just edited and put the log4j.properties